# GUI structure organise

Tags: java, user-interface, structure, organization

How would one best organise his GUI. I have a JFrame which will hold my application. Currently I have put all JPanel, JTables and others which will fill up the JFRame inside the custom JFrame class.

I instantiate these components there and save them in a local field. Would it be a better practice as to make a seperate class for each JPanel,JTable and use getters and setters to manipulate the objects?

For example. My current GUI class is about 3500 lines long which gets more complicated over time.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT (he wanted screenie):

[image: Targui - The game]

Comment: maybe you should ask this question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: You think? Wheres the code to review?

Comment: linked in my comment before :)

Comment: I mean where is the code that others can review on codereview :P Point of the site is to review code no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely suggest you start to separate your GUI components into different files, it will help in the long run. As far as best practice goes, I think it is better than cluttering a file with multiple classes even if they are related to each other. The only benefit I can see is you have only 1 file to open to see all the GUI code.

As you said, having a long class (3500ish lines) can make it troublesome to maintain. Organize them in proper packages too while at it. Like making a gui package, or whatever name you feel is appropriate, and so on.

Good advices are given in the answers of the [questions tagged user-interface and organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface+organization)

Comment: This is the kind of the answer that I am looking for. Thanks for the second time Jonathan.

Comment: @crashystar if you haven't already, check the [questions tagged user-interface and organization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface+organization), they don't actually answer directly your question but they do offer good advices

Answer (score 1):

Break up your GUI code into custom panels.

ie:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel { .. }
```

You should be able to break up the frame into logically distinct panels.

For a busy frame maybe I would have three custom panels. But this can drastically vary depending on what you have.

Also have a **controller** class. The controller handles backend calls to delegates, and event listening. Your GUI classes, eg customer panels, or custom frame should contain barely any if or loop statements. All that kind of logic should be in your controller.

Comment: if you have 3500 lines of code, then you are not using enough custom panels.

Comment: I am making a game GUI, but still no matter what the GUI is for how can you say I have to many? There's no way of knowing it without seeing the code.

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Of the game UI? Will do :) Your edited answer is more of a help.

Comment: yes  ........... usually a screenshot can give you visual clues on where to break it down into custom panels.

Comment: ^^ I added it for you. About using the controller is a good idea.

Comment: I would have GridPanel (left), SpeelPanel.... then three SpeelPanels would go into a component called DetailsPanel (right). That would be my gut feeling.

Comment: For the moment it's just a JTable at the left and a JPanel at the the right which consists out of a upper JPanel and a lower. The lower gets switched by the CardLayout. Anyhow why would you break them up into custom panels anyhow? I have enough with the normal ones. On the other hand does it look nice, you are the first to see it tbh.

Comment: it does look nice :) even though i have no idea what it does :)

Answer (score 0):

More complex GUI code is usually [generated by an IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html) and not hand-coded.  Sometimes, you might edit the generated code to get certain effects, but for very complex setups it becomes overly burdensome to hand-write the Swing code.  Better to use a tool to generate it for you.

If you already have 3,500 lines of code, it's probably time for you to consider a GUI builder to take some of this work away from you.  The learning curve can be steep, and it's not the easiest thing to do, but I would suggest it's way easier than hand-modification of a large GUI.

So basically, the answer is that for moderate/complex GUIs, people don't usually do it the way that you're doing it.

Comment: I am using a GUI builder to create each JPanel and it's components in it. When having 300+ components I don't like writing GridBagLayout :/

Comment: This also not an answer to my question :/